# Trigger mocked callback argument with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Using Jest, I'd like to trigger the `configure` callback argument. If I were to write this with a `sinon` stub, I could do something like `configure.yields('my value')`. Does Jest have anything similar? To help illustrate what I'm after, I created a simple example.

I've imported `mymodule`, instantiated, and called the `configure` function. I'd like my test to trigger this callback. i.e. `(err, results) => ...`

```js
import MyModule from 'mymodule';

export function execute(key, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new MyModule().configure(key, value, (err, result) => {
          // I need my test to trigger this section of code...
          return resolve('my resolved value')
      })
  })
}
```

This test is mocking `MyModule` and setting `configure` to a `jest.fn()`. While I have everything mocked, I'm not able to specify the `configure` args and trigger a specific argument. Ideally, I'd like to do something like `mockFn.yields('my value')` to trigger the `configure` callback.

```
import MyModule from 'mymodule';

jest.mock('mymodule');
describe('Test Example', () => {
  test('should trigger mocked args callback', async () => {
      const mockFn = jest.fn();
      const key = 'my_key';
      const value = 'my_value';

      const actual = require('./src/my-service');

      MyModule.mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            configure: mockFn
        };
      });

      await actual.execute(key, value)

      // how can I trigger the mocked configure argument callback?
  });
});
```

> Test currently fails because it cannot trigger the callback function. Error states: `Async callback was not invoked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that a promise that test `async` function returns wasn't settled. This happens because `execute` returns a pending promise, mocked `configure` doesn't call a callback that is supposed to resolve it.

`configure` should be mocked correctly and behave the same way as original implementation regarding callback argument:

```
mockFn.mockImplementation((key, value, cb) => cb(null, 'some result'));
const promise = actual.execute(key, value);
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledWith(key, value, expect.any(Function));
await expect(promise).resolves.toBe('my resolved value');
```

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you!